# how to use maven to trigger eclipse project build?

Tags: eclipse, class, maven, build

when I'm using  mvn install, and found that the number of compiling sources is different from that built from eclipse project  build.

that is when compiled from mvn there's info message  telling
[INFO] Compiling **359** source files to E:\workspace\project\target\classes

but when using eclipse-> project -> build project, there's over 400  classes, that means some classes are not compiled when using maven.

Is there anyone ever met similar problem?

ps: the tried with JDK 1.7, JDK1.8 and maven 3.2.1, 3.3, 3.1.1 and meet the same problem.

Comment: Interesting, really, but you missed ask a question

Comment: Thanks @michaldo ! Added question.

Comment: Maybe it is stupid and obvious but 1 source file can produce 2 or more class files.